# How to access Oracle Apex variables from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX but am unsure how to access the following variables from an external javascript file that may be located on the app server or stored in Shared Components -> Static Files.

```
:APP_ID
:APP_PAGE_ID
:APP_SESSION
```

How can I reference the values for each of the above from javascript (stored as a Static File)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These values get rendered on the page as hidden items like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p_flow_id" value="4000" id="pFlowId" />
<input type="hidden" name="p_flow_step_id" value="4150" id="pFlowStepId" />
<input type="hidden" name="p_instance" value="6528421540413702" id="pInstance" />
```

so you can reference them as:

```
$v('pFlowId') // APP_ID
$v('pFlowStepId') // APP_PAGE_ID
$v('pInstance') // SESSION
```

It's a pity they aren't named the same as the session state!

Comment: What about APP_USER?

Comment: @6190 APP_USER isn't, you would need to create your own hidden page item to hold that.

Comment: @6055 do `var app_user = '&APP_USER.';` in the page detail / section "JavaScript" / textarea "Function and Global Variable Declaration".  You can then use it elsewhere in the page.

Answer (score 7):

Since APEX 5 you can also use [apex.item](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/apex-item.htm) instead of [$v](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/Non-namespace-Javascript-APIs.htm), as described [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6341/index-en.html):

```
apex.item('pFlowId').getValue() // APP_ID
apex.item('pFlowStepId').getValue() // APP_PAGE_ID
apex.item('pInstance').getValue() // APP_SESSION
```

Both $v and apex.item require that the "apex" namespace has already been loaded at the time you try to access the values. If you ever need to access them before that, you can also use JavaScript only instead:

```
document.getElementById('pFlowId').value; // APP_ID
document.getElementById('pFlowStepId').value; // APP_PAGE_ID
document.getElementById('pInstance').value; // APP_SESSION
```